# Karma test an Angular X (5) Component with a custom pipe that uses a built in pipe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have built a custom pipe to format currencies, which uses the decimal pipe in it. Now I want to Karma test my component, which uses my custom pipe.

Here is my custom pipe:

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";
import { CURRENCY } from "./customCurrency.enums";
import { DecimalPipe } from "@angular/common";

type CurrencySymbol = keyof typeof CURRENCY;
type CurrencyHandler = {
  [x in CurrencySymbol]: (value: string) => string;
};

@Pipe({
  name: "customCurrency",
})
export class CustomCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) { }

  transform(amount: string, currency: CurrencySymbol): string {
    const currencyHandler: CurrencyHandler = {
      Euro: (value: string): string => {
        const formatValue = value.toString().replace(",", ".");
        return this.setCharAt(formatValue, formatValue.length - 3, ",") + " " + CURRENCY.Euro;
      },
    };

    return currencyHandler[currency](this.decimalPipe.transform(amount, "1.2-2"));
  }

  private setCharAt(str, index, chr) {
    if (index > str.length - 1) {
      return str;
    }
    return str.substr(0, index) + chr + str.substr(index + 1);
  }
}
```

I am using it in the HTML part only in my component:
`<span class="col-s currency">{{invoice.totalAmount | customCurrency:"Euro"}}</span>`

This pipe is member of my SharedModule. So I imported it into my testbed configuration.

Now I want to test the component with this template here:

```js
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";

import { ApprovalsComponent } from "./approvals.component";
import { MaterialModule } from "../shared/material.module";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
import { DataService } from "../core/data.service";
import { SharedModule } from "../shared/shared.module";

describe("ApprovalsComponent", () => {
  let component: ApprovalsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ApprovalsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        SharedModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        ApprovalsComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
        DataService,
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ApprovalsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it("should create", () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I am always getting the error:
`NullInjectorError: No provider for DecimalPipe!`

I have tried out all kind of import or declaration variations, without any success. What am I doing wrong?
Can someone tell, where I have to import/declare/provide what. My custom pipe is part of shared module. What if I want to test a component which uses it, but is in a different module. And what if I want to use the pipe in a component within the same module?

Comment: Did you try adding the DecimalPipe to the declarations?

Comment: As written in my last sentence, I have tried all variations of imports, declarations and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I restarted my complete environment and added the `DecimalPipe` again to my providers and now it works. I have no clue why it works now and it did not before, but it works with this configuration when I am in another module:

```js
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        SharedModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        ApprovalsComponent,
      ],
      providers: [
        DataService,
        DecimalPipe,
      ],
      schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

And with this configuration when I am in the same module:

```js
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MaterialModule,
      ],
      declarations: [
        LineItemListComponent,
        CustomCurrencyPipe,
      ],
      schemas: [
        CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
      ],
      providers: [
        DecimalPipe,
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: This works for other Components you reference from inside this Component also. Add your *Referenced*Component under `providers`